# Pointer member of Fortran derived type isn't copied

Tags: fortran

When I initialize an object inside of a function or subroutine and attempt to return it, a pointer member that was set in the constructor seems to become undefined (although I may be misinterpreting what is happening).

I'd like to understand exactly what is happening here, and if possible, how to initialize a pointer inside a constructor, then return the object from a function or subroutine while preserving the pointer.

MWE:

```
program mwe
  implicit none

  type a
    integer var
  end type a

  type b
    type(a), pointer :: elt
  end type b

  interface b
    procedure construct_b
  end interface

  type(b) val_func, val_sub

  val_func = get_new_b(52)
  write(*,*) 'using function: ', val_func%elt%var

  call new_b(val_sub, 55)
  write(*,*) 'using subroutine: ', val_sub%elt%var

contains

  function construct_b(elt) result(r)
    class(a), target, intent(in) :: elt
    type(b) r

    r%elt => elt
  end function

  function get_new_b(n) result(r)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    type(b) r

    type(a) elt

    elt = a(n)
    r = b(elt)
    write(*,*) 'get_new_b:      ', r%elt%var
  end function

  subroutine new_b(r, n)
    type(b), intent(inout) :: r
    integer, intent(in) :: n

    type(a) elt

    elt = a(n)
    r = b(elt)
    write(*,*) 'new_b:            ', r%elt%var
  end subroutine

end program mwe
```

Using gfortran 5.4.0,

```
$ gfortran -o mwe.x mwe.f90
$ ./mwe.x
 get_new_b:                52
 using function:    127919104
 new_b:                      55
 using subroutine:    127919104
```

The output I expect is:

```
 get_new_b:                52
 using function:           52
 new_b:                      55
 using subroutine:           55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `get_new_b` procedure, you're doing:

```
type(a) elt    
elt = a(n)
r = b(elt)
```

That means your are creating a local variable `elt` inside the function, then you're calling `constructor_b` (through `b` interface) with this variable. Inside `constructor_b`, what happens is:

```
type(b) r
r%elt => elt
```

I.e., you create a new `type(b)` variable and do a pointer associaton between its `elt` field and the variable `elt` you passed into.

The problem is: the actual argument `elt` you passed as a parameter is **local** to the scope of the function `get_new_b`. When the control turns back to the main program, the target of the pointer (that `elt` variable you created inside the function) ceases to exist the pointer is then 'dangling'.

You should never have a pointer to a variable that is out of scope.

In the code you provided, it makes more sense to have an allocatable component. You sould have a pointer component only when you want to point it to other existing variables (whose memory is managed by other parts of yout code, not by the type itself).

But if a pointer is what you want, be sure that its target will never get undefined before the variable with the pointer component.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  How would I do the same thing with allocatable?  I've thought of allocatable as limited to arrays, and I only want one scalar value here.

Comment: Scalars can have the allocatable attribute too, in your case I think that just by changing POINTER to ALLOCATABLE in the component (and changing pointer association => to assignment =) will work. Actually, it only makes sense to have an allocatable component there if the component's type is huge in memory.

Comment: The real reason I wanted a pointer was so `elt` could be `class(a)` and I could take advantage of runtime polymorphism to pass child types of `a` to the `b` constructor. So although `a` is not huge in memory, it needs to be allocatable or pointer to compile.

Comment: Good reason. Allocatable will do just fine. You can pass a variable with the runtime type you want and allocate your component with source or mold: allocate(r%elt, source=elt). Other option is to pass only the argument over the constructor and not having and intermediate type(a) to copy. E.g. you refactor your construct_b to receive an integer n as a parameter and do: allocate(a :: r%elt) and then: r%elt%var = n.